# "TypeError: Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert." when I update pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have update pandas from 0.20 to 0.21.1 (anaconda distribution) and I have an message error: "TypeError: Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert." when I executed this code with python 0.20 it worked perfectly !!

```
 PvBrut['Date'] = PvBrut.Date.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris')+timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Comment: As the error suggests, try removing `.dt.tz_localize('UTC')` and running it again.

Comment: cool,  It work's but I don't understand why !THKS

Comment: I don't either, because I can't see your data. My guess is that the latest release of pandas seems to have read your datetimes so as to be  timezone aware, so localising it was no longer needed.

Answer (score 5):

Datetime is already localized to a timezone, **UTC**.

Don't call `.tz_localize` on it. Just convert it by using `.tz_convert('UTC')`