# Pands upgrade and Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert

Tags: python, pandas

So I have upgraded pandas to 0.24.2 and I have a:

```
 Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert.
```

For this line :

```
df["Created"] = df['Created'] = df['Created'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/London', nonexistent='shift_forward').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
```

But I need to convert it because if not a I have a non existent time error.

So I've see this message:

["TypeError: Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert." when I update pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034875/typeerror-already-tz-aware-use-tz-convert-to-convert-when-i-update-pandas)

Here is my code:

```
data = result["Document"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Created"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Created"])

df["Created"] = df['Created'] = df['Created'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/London', nonexistent='shift_forward').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
```

Comment: How about a sample of the input data that will round out your [mcve] so we can reproduce on our side?

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Created"] = df['Created'] = df['Created']...
```

Is likely incorrect, but not likely the root cause of the error.

The `Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert.` error cannot be reproduced as follows.  Likely due to absence of proper input data.

The input data below starts with the `Datetime` as naive (no tz) hoping that the calls to `tz_localize` elucidate the error.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""Created,open,high,low,close,volume
2019-04-02 05:59:00,381.00,381.00,379.70,379.70,0
2019-04-02 05:58:00,380.90,380.90,380.85,380.85,5040
,380.85,380.95,380.65,380.95,9615
2019-04-02 05:56:00,380.60,381.20,380.60,381.00,13041
2019-04-02 05:55:00,379.80,380.60,379.80,380.60,19586""")

#df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",", index_col="Created", parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")

df["Created"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Created"])
print(df)

df['Created'] = df['Created'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/London', nonexistent='shift_forward').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Paris')
print(df)
```

The result is

```
0.24.2
              Created    open    high     low   close  volume
0 2019-04-02 05:59:00  381.00  381.00  379.70  379.70       0
1 2019-04-02 05:58:00  380.90  380.90  380.85  380.85    5040
2                 NaT  380.85  380.95  380.65  380.95    9615
3 2019-04-02 05:56:00  380.60  381.20  380.60  381.00   13041
4 2019-04-02 05:55:00  379.80  380.60  379.80  380.60   19586
                    Created    open    high     low   close  volume
0 2019-04-02 06:59:00+02:00  381.00  381.00  379.70  379.70       0
1 2019-04-02 06:58:00+02:00  380.90  380.90  380.85  380.85    5040
2                       NaT  380.85  380.95  380.65  380.95    9615
3 2019-04-02 06:56:00+02:00  380.60  381.20  380.60  381.00   13041
4 2019-04-02 06:55:00+02:00  379.80  380.60  379.80  380.60   19586
```